# OpenMP Compilation error: ‘reduction’ is not valid for ‘#pragma omp taskloop’

Tags: c++, openmp

I'm trying to compile a simple program using OpenMP, but I am getting the following error, even though in the OpenMP specification it says that it is a proper construct.

**Error**

```
file.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
file.cc:18:26: error: ‘reduction’ is not valid for ‘#pragma omp taskloop’
     #pragma omp taskloop reduction(+:sum)
```

**Program**

```
#include <iostream>

#include "omp.h"

int main(){


    int size = 1000;
    int sum = 0;
    #pragma omp parallel 
    #pragma omp taskloop reduction(+:sum)
    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i){
        sum += 1;
    }

    std::cout << "Sum: " << sum << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

When I output the version with --version I get gcc (GCC) 8.4.0. Altought, the installed version on Arch is 9.3.0

I compiled with

```
g++ -fopenmp file.cc
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

What compile do you use?

This code compiles and work with GCC 9.3.

```
int main(){
    int size = 1000;
    int sum = 0;
    #pragma omp parallel for simd reduction(+:sum)
    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i){
        sum += 1;
    }
    std::cout << "Sum: " << sum << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But this code while still compiles will crash on execution.

```
int main(){
    int size = 1000;
    int sum = 0;
    #pragma omp parallel 
    #pragma omp taskloop reduction(+:sum)
    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i){
        sum += 1;
    }
    std::cout << "Sum: " << sum << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[Code on godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/z/ZbEj8Y)

Comment: g++ (GCC) 8.4.0 or 9.3 not sure, the package differs from the --version output, I just updated the answer

Comment: Then put this.
 `printf("gcc version: %d.%d.%d\n", _GNUC__,__GNUC_MINOR__,__GNUC_PATCHLEVEL__);` 
in you code and see what compiler is used.

Comment: Then I get a compilation error saying that _GNUC_ is not declared in this scope

Comment: `__GNUC__`  is not declared? May be then is is clang `__clang_major__`?

Comment: Okay, it was missing a _, The output is gcc version: 8.4.0

Comment: I don't understand why, since the package installed has a newer version...